# pseudo element control with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to make a **talkbubble** styled div- box change colors completely upon being clicked.

I ran into a problem of getting the `:before` pseudo element that I'm using (*to shape the arrow for the talkbubble*) to actually change colors with the rest of the element, as seen here:

**HTML**

```
<div class="clickables">
        <div class="talkbubble">
            <input type="hidden" class="tbselector" value="sbselection_1">
            <div class="thumbnail">
               <img src="images/thumbnail1.png" height="33" width="30" />
             </div>
             <div class="words">Commons</div>
         </div>
         <div class="talkbubble">
             <input type="hidden" class="tbselector" value="sbselection_2">
             <div class="thumbnail">
                 <img src="images/thumbnail1.png" height="33" width="30" align="middle" />
             </div>
             <div class="words">crossroads</div>
         </div>
         .
         . More and more
         .
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** <sup>Just Relevant</sup>

```
.talkbubble {
   background: white;
   color: rgb(0,0,0);
   height: 40px;
   margin-top: 1%;
   margin-left: 48%;
   margin-right: auto;
   position: relative;
   width: 150px;    
 }
.talkbubble:before {
   border-top: 10px solid transparent; 
   border-right: 10px solid white; 
   border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
   content:""; 
   height: 0; 
   position: absolute; 
   right: 100%; 
   top: 10px; 
   width: 0;    
}
.talkbubble:before.clicked {
   border-right-color:#666666;
}
.talkbubble:hover{
    background-color: rgb(194,194,194)!important;
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
}
.talkbubble:hover:before{
   border-right-color: rgb(194,194,194)!important;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.clickables').on('click','.talkbubble',function () {
     $(this).parent().find('.talkbubble').css('background-color','#ffffff');
     $(this).css('background-color', '#666666');
 });
```

Here is a Demo http://jsfiddle.net/petiteco24601/3xuuq2fx/

I did some research and it seems a little inconclusive. For the most part, a lot of what I found was basically saying that there's no way to really force javascript on a pseudo element, since the pseudo element doesn't REALLY exist.

However, with more research, I found things like http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-animationstransitions-bug-fixed-in-webkit/ and [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css/2610741#2610741) that say that those bugs were fixed and it is possible with some browsers to use javascript on pseudo elements. What's the actual deal? How extensively can a person control pseudo elements?

Comment: just add an extra class, inline style isn't best practice anyways..

Answer (score 2):

The way you can go is add or remove a new class.

- First remove the `!important` declaration on your CSS is bad practice and can be conflictive later.
- Then make a new class with the change you want :

  ```
  .clicked {
      background:#666;
  }
  .clicked:before {
      border-right-color:#666;
  }
  ```
- Then with Jquery add / remove the class:

  ```
  $('.clickables').on('click','.talkbubble',function () {
      $(this).siblings('.talkbubble').removeClass('clicked');
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
  });
  ```

Check this [DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xuuq2fx/1/)

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense to do the class. I take that to mean that they still haven't exactly made it possible to automatically attach the pseudo-elements with the elements when you give it a jquery command. Do you think it'll be likely in the near future, or will we just always have to stick with finding these round-about ways to manage pseudo-elements?

Comment: @CosetteGirardot I don't think that can be a good idea to me inline styles must be avoided. But can be a godd tool to access another properties like change the content or fade the pseudo elements. And many others.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for only CSS solution without using javascript. Here it is:

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xuuq2fx/4/)**

I wrapped each list-item block with a label and radio button in HTML code. and in CSS, I added the following code:

```
.talkbubble {
    display: inline-block;
    /* other styles */
}

:checked + .talkbubble {
    background-color: #666;
}
:checked + .talkbubble:before {
    border-right-color: #666;
}
:checked + .talkbubble:hover:before {
    border-right-color: #666;
}
.clickables input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

..and also removed `!important` as suggested by Danko.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have been able to change pseudo CSS declarations has been to create individual `<style>` tags with and id associated with the class of the elements they are applied to. I.E.

```
<style id="talkbubble_style">
    .talkbubble:before{
    border-right-color:#666666;
    }
</style>
```

So, when you handle the click event, you get the style element and change the `innerHTML` to whatever CSS you want, along with the `!important` option added to each definition. Like this:

```
$('.clickables').on('click','.talkbubble',function () {
     $(this).parent().find('.talkbubble').css('background-color','#ffffff');
     $(this).css('background-color', '#666666');
     $('#talkbubble_style').html('.talkbubble:before{border-right-color:#666666!important;}');
});
```